# How can I set my application to display everything in English on the live server (Despite live server's settings)?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am having this problem with my ASP.Net application and I have no idea how I can solve it: In order for my date-related parameters to be the same over the whole application, I am taking the date from SQL Server via a stored procedure.

My problem is that when I am testing on the local server, everything works ok (everything is displayed in English as it should be), but when I am publishing it on live (on my company's server), the date-related parameters (ex. month names) are displayed in my country's language (which is not English). I assume it has to do with the settings of the live server. Is there any chance I could somehow set inside my application that the language should be English, despite of localization, settings etc. of the live server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it in web.config

```
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-US" />
```

Look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this settings in your Web.Config by specifying globalization Element. For reference see the following url: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy4kkhe0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

The attribute to set you interest in are "culture" and "uiCulture".